# MIgration issue for JSF projects

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

Please check the below logs ...Does anyone knows about this error
Migrating JDEVTP4 from JDEV11.1.2.3 using ADF and JSF technology

```
Server Logs

<25 Jan, 2013 12:44:39 PM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101164> <User defined class com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener is not a Listener, as it does not implement the correct interface(s).> 
<ConfigureListener> <contextInitialized> Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:180)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:96)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.<init>(UnifiedRenderKit.java:125)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.createRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKit.java:107)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKitFactory.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.CoreRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(CoreRenderKitFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.CoreRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(CoreRenderKitFactory.java:55)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKitFactory.java:53)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.addRenderKits(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.process(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:159)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:270)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ValidatorConfigProcessor.process(ValidatorConfigProcessor.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ConverterConfigProcessor.process(ConverterConfigProcessor.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ComponentConfigProcessor.process(ComponentConfigProcessor.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:341)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:216)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:338)
    ... 37 more
<25 Jan, 2013 12:45:11 PM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:293)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.<init>(UnifiedRenderKit.java:125)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.createRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKit.java:107)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKitFactory.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.CoreRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(CoreRenderKitFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.CoreRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(CoreRenderKitFactory.java:55)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<FactoryFinder$FactoryManager> <getFactory> Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
<ConfigureListener> <contextDestroyed> Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:996)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:331)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:329)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:482)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextDestroyedEvent(EventsManager.java:200)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.destroy(WebAppServletContext.java:3224)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletContextManager.destroyContext(ServletContextManager.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.unloadWebApp(HttpServer.java:461)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.destroyContexts(WebAppModule.java:1535)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.deactivate(WebAppModule.java:507)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.previous(ModuleStateDriver.java:387)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:223)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:215)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.deactivate(ModuleStateDriver.java:141)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.deactivate(ScopedModuleDriver.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.deactivate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:261)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$2.previous(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:547)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:223)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:215)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.deactivate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.deactivate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:184)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.previous(BaseDeployment.java:642)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.previousState(StateMachineDriver.java:223)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:63)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:180)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:96)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
<25 Jan, 2013 12:45:11 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application 'DEV_4.5'.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.<init>(UnifiedRenderKit.java:125)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.createRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKit.java:107)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKitFactory.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.CoreRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(CoreRenderKitFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.CoreRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(CoreRenderKitFactory.java:55)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: What does your `WebappLifecycleListener` look like? Does i actually implement `Listener`?

Comment: public class WebappLifecycleListener
    implements javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener,
               javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener,
               javax.servlet.ServletRequestAttributeListener,
               javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener,
               javax.servlet.ServletContextAttributeListener,
               javax.servlet.ServletContextListener

Comment: So 'no'. Then that is your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you try to do. You want to migrate an existing application from what application server to which one? What technologies uses the application you want to migrate?
However you may find a possible solution [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10680643).

Comment: As per your solution in my JSF projects if i removed those jars then how it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your JSF listeners should implement the [listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/event/FacesListener.html) from the JSF library. If you want to install Servlet listeners in you application, you should do so through `web.xml`...